# Changing the class of a div onClick with a separate element

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, motion

So, I'm trying to create a site where if you click on a link, a panel slides out from the side w. more information using jQuery and css

The panel is a div whose position is absolute, and is moved just outside of the screen. When the link is clicked, I want the panel to move into place. Essentially, I would like to change the class of that div so that the absolute positioning moves the div into the screen...

So, I know how to rig a div or  so that it changes it's own class, but I don't know how to hook up an  to a separate div so that it controls the div. I also am not sure what functions to add so that it slides into place instead of just appearing...

I'm pretty new to jQuery...so if anyone can help it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to animate its position, or margin/padding.

You hook into the object that serves as the trigger:

```
$("#trigger").click( function(){
});
```

And when clicked, re-position the element using `.animate()`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#trigger").click( function(){
        // Adjust the effect (2000 miliseconds)
        $("#moreinfo").animate( { opacity: 1.0, left: 0 }, 2000 ); 
    });
});
</script>
```

And then in the CSS somewhere, we initially hide the element far off screen.

```
#moreinfo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left: -2000px; // You can adjust based upon the actual dimensions of the object
}
```

Comment: So would those first to bits of text be placed in the header?

Comment: The Javascript should be inside your `$(document).ready(function() {...})` function. It doesn't matter whether it's in the header or body.

Comment: So, that didn't work. I'm sure it's my bad, I just don't know what I'm doing wrong... here's a link: http://dualdigitaldesign.com/client/highcue/

Comment: You're pretty close, but you need to first introduce jQuery on the page. I've updated the JavaScript code above :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use jQuery's animate functions or you could simply do it in regular javascript with something like this attached as an `onclick=` event on the div you want to control the sliding panel:

```
function slide(slider, data, step, callback) {
  slider.style.left = data+"px";
  data += step;
  if(dataIn <= data && data <= dataOut) {
    setTimeout(function() { slide(slider,data,step,callback) }, 15);
  } else if(callback && (typeof(callback) == 'function')) { 
    callback();}
}
```

And this way, you can simply set the event on the div you want to click to slide:

```
function click() {
  var data = 0;
  var step = 15;
  var slider = document.GetElementById("sliderDiv");
  slide(slider,data,step);
}
```

And in the future, you can now use a callback() if you need to run something asynchronously. :)